# Giving a common path for a group of files into a bash script

Tags: path, paste

The purpose of following script is to merge several tables and put them in an specific directory by using `paste` command.

```
for i in {1..30}
 do
 paste ./directory"$i"/table1.txt table2.txt ... table20.txt > ./merged_tables/tables_directory"$i".txt
done
```

I am getting this error:

```
 paste: file table2: No such file or directory
```

By writing the path to each table it would work but I do not want to write the path too many times, so is there any other way to do that without write the path to each table? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

```
for (( i = 1; i <= 30; ++i )); do
    ( cd "directory$i" &&
      paste tableNC023.txt tableNC088.txt tableNC102.txt ... ) >"./merged_tables/tables_directory$i.txt"
done
```

This uses `cd` to enter the directory in a subshell.  If the `cd` is successful, `paste` is used to create the combined data.  The output from the subshell is redirected to you result file as before.

Since the `cd` is done in a subshell, no `cd ..`, `cd -` or `cd "$OLDPWD"` is needed to "step back" for the next iteration.

---

Alternative, for neater code:

```
tables=( tableNC023.txt tableNC088.txt tableNC102.txt
         more tables here )

for (( i = 1; i <= 30; ++i )); do
    ( cd "directory$i" &&
      paste "${tables[@]}" ) >"./merged_tables/tables_directory$i.txt"
done
```

---

My use of `for (( i ... ))` rather than `for i in {...}` is purely based on personal preference.

Comment: Excuse me, maybe I should have said that the tables do not follow a correlative numeration, they are more like `tableNC023` `tableNC088` `tableNC102` etc.

Comment: @Fersal See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in {1..30}
 do
 pushd directory"$i" >/dev/null 2>&1 || continue
 paste table1.txt table2.txt ... table20.txt > ../merged_tables/tables_directory"$i".txt
 popd >/dev/null 2>&1
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using brace expansion, you could also use it here.

Either have the expansion generate the sequence of numbers (`..` is literal):

```
for i in {1..30}; do
    paste ./directory"$i"/table{1..20}.txt > ./merged_tables/tables_directory"$i".txt
done
```

Or list them manually (fill in the `...`):

```
for i in {1..30}; do
    paste ./directory"$i"/table{1,2,...,20}.txt > ./merged_tables/tables_directory"$i".txt
done
```

That is, assuming you don't just want all files in the directory that match the pattern:

```
for i in {1..30}; do
    paste ./directory"$i"/table*.txt > ./merged_tables/tables_directory"$i".txt
done
```